# How to print a specific div of a html page with css on a custom paper size

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, printing

I am a making a bill printing webapp on node js which automatically enters data of the qr code scanned and adds it to the main bill.I've figured out the scanning and adding part but I'm stuck on the printing part.

**I want to create a bill of size 9in x 7in on the screen and print exactly as it is on the same sized paper.**

I've tried this [solution](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-the-contents-of-a-div-element-using-javascript/) but this doesn't include the css and the page size options.

I've also tried [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page) but this is also of no help as the page is printed by the browser page dialogue box or the printer dialogue box.I changed the dimensions of paper in the printer dialogue box but my whole page was being printed with iregular scaling.

Please help me out here I'm stuck on this for about two weeks now.

Comment: Actually, the "print" can be a normal page but with styles. Try pressing "ctrl+P" on this page. It will look very different because of `@media print` in CSS.

Comment: And if you use the method from your first link, then you are creating new window, so CSS styles should also be copied there.

Comment: Should I copy the styling of my div to the new html page in the new window if I'm going by the solution of the first link @Anton